# A cryptographic tool for specific fields in data

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I was thinking of building a piece of software that would be able to encrypt specific fields in a data file. So I started to consider writing some code in Python using cryptographic libraries. However I wonder: is it really safe? Should I rather use existing cryptographic tools?

If so, do you know a good cryptographic tool I could rely on? The only tools I find only encrypt entire files or disks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This greatly depends (obviously), on how you write it.

There are libraries like [cryptography](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography) which already provide this solution though and are considered very safe.

https://github.com/fugue/credstash, for instance, which is widely used, uses cryptography.

https://github.com/lyft/confidant uses it also.

I implemented a locally usable secret store using cryptography (which you could use to encrypt any type of data) - https://github.com/nir0s/ghost which you could use as a reference implementation or simply use it (hope I'm not breaking any rules here)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is very useful.

Comment: Please mark this as answered then :) Unless it isn't, of course.